# Changing the src="" with JS onclick

Tags: include

This is my first questions on Stack Overflow - Usually i find all the answers very quick.

Following situation:

Im working on a small page at work, that is hosted on our local drive - that means im working without a webserver. So i cant include for example my header or sidebar via php or JS, because IE security settings are not allowing it from the company. And we not able to use chrome in unsecure mode or FF.

Now im working with old iframes, what sucks but finish the job quiet good.

Now my scenario.

I have the menu.html with my menu tabs

```html
   <!-- MAIN MENU TABS -->
        <div class="cm-flex">
            <div class="main_tab">
            <a href="lis.html">
            <span>Server Status</span>
            </a>
            <a href="lis-problemtickets.html">
            <span>Ongoing Issues</span>
            </a>
            <a href="lis-newsletter.html">
            <span class="active">Newsletter</span>
            </a>
            <a href="lis-search.html">
            <span>Easy Search</span>
            </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- MAIN MENU TABS / END -->
```

In the same file i got my iframe:

```html
        <!-- MAIN CONTENT FRAME -->
        <div id="fix">
        <iframe src="newsletter-archive.html" class="frame-main"></iframe>
        </div>
        <!-- MAIN CONTENT FRAME END -->
```

Is it possible with JS, that when i click on a menu tab,  the src="" content from the iFrame changes to the specific site i clicked on?

Update:

I make it work with

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test").click(function(){
        $("#frame").attr("src", "newsletter-knowledge-base.html");
    });
});
```

```html
<a href="#" id="test">
 <span class="active">Newsletter</span>
</a>

<div id="fix">
 <iframe src="newsletter-archive.html" class="frame-main" id="frame"></iframe>
 </div>
```

Now somebody knows how i can take for example a value in #test to add to the src content?

Comment: To strictly answer to your question : yes it is possible.

Comment: Do you have maybe a example for it?

Comment: I don't, but I can give you the general idea : for each tab, on click, prevent the default behavior and get the `href` then change the iframe's `src` to that tab's `href`

Comment: Sure, just assign whatever attribute name you want to the #test element, get that attr with jquery, and assign it to the iframe's src

Comment: @DevinFields can you help me a bit?
Im playing around at the moment.. but i think its not correct.. 

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".").click(function(){
     var idmenu = $(this).attr('id');
     var urlmenu= $(this).attr('src');
        $("#frame").attr("src", "newsletter-knowledge-base.html");
    });
});

Comment: $(".") this selector isn't referencing any class. Should be $('.whatever-your-class-is')